# MySQL Connection Timed Out using Docker toolbox

Tags: php, mysql, docker-toolbox

I am trying to set up a CakePHP project on my personal computer. Everything seems to works as expected except I not able to connect to MySQL. CakePHP keeps outputting this error message:

```
Database Error
PDOException
Documentation API
Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out

If you are using SQL keywords as table column names, you can enable identifier quoting for your database connection in config/app.php.
```

I am using a similar set up at my job and it is able to connect to the remote MySQL. The biggest difference is that I am using Docker toolbox on my Windows 8 machine, while at my job I use Docker Desktop. In particular, I access my application using `http://192.168.99.100` instead of `localhost`.

I am positive that my credentials are correct.

Another hunch I had is that I need to specify the MySQL port. Currently, it is not set. If it does need to be set, what do I set it to?

Does anyone have any pointers of how I can resolve this? I greatly appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue.

I was not authorized to access the AWS RDS MySQL with my IP.